# Show that $F_2^4$ is a union of three proper subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm just a bit confused about getting my head around this. I have seen proofs that say that a union of subspaces is only a subspace iff at least one subspace contains all the others, so, I'm not sure how this union of proper subspaces would work. Would somebody be able to show me how to do this?

There is also a follow-on question, show that there are 35 2-dimensional subspace of $F^4_2$ but I believe I can do this. We know that any 2-dimensional subspace is isomorphic to $F^2_2$, which itself has 6 choices of basis elements. Now, there are $(2^4 - 1)(2^4 - 2)$ total choices of two linearly independent vectors in $F^4_2$ and hence if we divide this total number of L.I. vectors by the result of 6 bases per subspace, we get the result of 35. Is this a valid method?

(*NOTE:* $F_2$ being the field {0,1})

Thanks, Helen.

Comment: I think you mean: a union of two subspaces is a subspace if and only if *one* of them is contained in *the other*.  if the two are contained in each other they must be the same space.

Comment: The union of **two** subspaces is a subspace only if one of them contains the other. But these are **three** subspaces.

Comment: @ajotatxe is correct.  If you have several subspaces, the union is a subspace if and only if one of them contains all of them.

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's what I mean, apologies for the confusing language used. I've hopefully edited it to be more clear now.

Comment: So *can* a vector space be equal to a union of proper subspaces?

Comment: I would assume so, since the question is asking? But I can't get my head around it. What I can't understand is, if the other two subspaces are contained in the third, what does taking the union contribute in terms of making a new subspace?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang If you consider $F_2^2$ it's quite easy: $F_2^2=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}\cup\{(0,0),(0,1)\}\cup\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Comment: @egreg Oh, I see now.  I am not used to thinking in finite fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easily verified by listing elements that $F_2^4=V_1\cup V_2\cup V_3$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
V_1&=\langle(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0)\rangle \\
V_2&=\langle(0,0,0,1),(0,0,1,0),(0,1,0,0)\rangle \\
V_3&=\langle(1,0,0,1),(1,1,0,1),(1,0,1,1)\rangle
\end{align*}

Maybe some insight into my approach will be helpful.  First I made the rather obvious choice for $V_1$.  From this I can obtain all vectors with last component $0$.  Next I made certain that not all vectors in $V_2$ have last component $0$.  Computing $V_1\cup V_2$, there are only three vectors not yet covered, which I chose as my basis for $V_3$.

Comment: I can't see how two of these are contained within the other though?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?  We have $V_1\cap V_2\cap V_3\neq\{id\}$, but I'm not sure that's relevant here.

Comment: I thought that there is a theorem which states that the union of subspaces is a subspace if and only if one of the subspaces being "unioned" contains all the others.

Comment: My example proves that this is not the case (at least for vector spaces over the finite field $F_2$).

Comment: It could be true in general for vector spaces over fields of characteristic $0$, but I would have to think about that before answering.

Comment: See the answer @slake gave also.

Comment: I understand now, I did not know that these theorems applied only to infinite fields, it makes a lot more sense now that that has been clarified. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @HelenByrne: The theorem that you (mis)remember can be also applied to finite fields under certain conditions, but these conditions are not satisfied here. See http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2746 .

Answer (score 1):

Here's a picture of something similar happening in $F_2^3$, perhaps it will give you an idea about what can be done in general.

[image]

In the picture, we could think of our subspaces as the spans of $\{e_1, e_3\}, \{e_2, e_3\},$ and $\{e_1 + e_2, e_3\}$, to obtain the blue, green, and purple subspaces respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this visualisation helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The set where two coordinates are equal is a subspace, and two of the first three coordinates must be equal.

The proofs you refer to apply only to infinite fields.  Any finite vector space is clearly equal to the union of its dimension 1 subspaces.

Comment: Ah, that makes MUCH more sense, thank you! I couldn't get my head around how it would work otherwise. Thanks for clarifying. By the way, would $span((1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)) \cup span((0,0,1,0)) \cup span((0,0,0,1))$ work?

Comment: @HelenByrne the vector $(0,1,1,0)$ does not belong to the union.  Unfortunately, sometimes it is necessary to write these all out...

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm confusing it with a sum of subspaces rather than a union.